# Troubleshooting SqlBulkCopy not doing minimal logging

Tags: sql-server, performance, import, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlbulkcopy

Based on the idea presented [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/122498/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-high-performance-inserts/), I've created a `QueuedDataReader` which wraps a `ConcurrentQueue` in an `IDataReader` so I can pass it to `SqlBulkCopy` and 'stream' data into the database.

It works ok, and pretty fast, but the log file grows quite dramatically, even though I believe I've implemented everything suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178096%28SQL.80%29.aspx) (and numerous other places).

Two possibly important details are:

- I'm inserting into a dozen tables in parallel (that is, one `Task` per table)
- The tables have `IDENTITY` columns (which SqlBulkCopy is not inserting into), so I don't think the 'SORT' provisos are relevant.

In addition to that:

- The tables are empty when I start inserting.
- I've tried both CLUSTERED and NONCLUSTERED indexes on the PRIMARY KEY, not much observable difference.
- I'm using `SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock`
- I've tried with and without UseInternalTransactions, and various BatchSizes.
- The database is in SIMPLE recovery mode
- The tables do have FK constraints, but I've tried disabling/re-enabling them and it doesn't stop the log file growing (during insertion)

The question:

- What are some things I could look at to try and troubleshoot what could be causing the log file growth?

Comment: Look at the log contents using fn_dblog (instructions available on the web). What is the bulk of the operations there? Maybe you can post a screenshot of a representative sample. Did you try no batch size (0)? Because only the first batch finds the table empty.

Comment: @usr, currently trying batch size 0, but that also means I have to do timeout 0, which feels... dangerous. I'll look into fn_dblog.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst writing my question, I discovered another excellent resource [here](http://www.sqlbi.com/wp-content/uploads/SqlBulkCopy-Performance-1.0.pdf), which pointed to BatchSize as a potential culprit.

> The results are quite surprising. If we use the BatchSize parameter,
> performance get worse and worse as we set it to lower values.
>
> Using a very small value for the batch size the network bandwidth
> stays well under 20% of usage for the whole process (please note that
> the 500 batch size graph upper limit is 25%, which is different from
> the other graphs). Any value below 10.000 decreases performance in a
> very heavy way, leading to very poor time and a heavy log file usage.
>
> When we reach 10.000 of Batch Size, then the difference in time among
> the various tests becomes very small. But, since we have 8 threads
> writing 750.000 rows each, then we only have 75 chunks of data sent
> from each thread. Needless to say, the best performance is obtained
> when we use 0 as BatchSize, sending the whole 750.000 rows in a single
> batch.
>
> It might be interesting to discover if there is any benefit, apart
> from performance, by using the BatchSize parameter. We did not find
> anything mentioned in the Books On Line nor have we ever seen anything
> interesting during our experience, this lead us to say that the best
> thing to do with BatchSize is to leave it to zero, which is its
> default value, since any value different from that will decrease the
> performance of the load process.

I had previously abandoned `BatchSize = 0` because of timeout errors, but by setting my `BulkCopyTimeout` to zero, I get some log file growth, but far less than previously.

**UPDATE**. After messing around for too long doing manual tests, I finally knuckled down to writing an automated test suite, trying variations of BatchSize(0-5000), enqueuing rates, and clustered/nonclustered indexes. (In my case, I'm writing data to a dozen tables in parallel).

This is what I've found:

- Tests of 200000 inserts: If primary keys are `CLUSTERED` **or** BatchSize is zero, I get *no* log file growth.
- Tests of 1 million inserts: even BatchSize=0 has the log file growing (though considerably less than for other BatchSizes). `CLUSTERED` still prevents log growth, whatever the BatchSize.
- Outside of those conditions, everything depends on insertion speed. As soon as I 'push' too hard, the log file starts growing.

*Note, my tests write data at a given rate into a queue wrapped in an IDataReader, which is dequeued by BulkInsert. One queue/BulkInsert for each table.* Next step is to try with bigger data sets.

Comment: It is definitely possible to get minimally-logged bulk inserts with non-empty tables. Not sure what's going wrong in your case because the "checklist" you posted seems quite good. I encourage you to look at the log records to see what is being written there. You should find 99% of them to be allocations.

Comment: The output from fn_dblog is rather difficult to interpret (and there's lots of it for a bulk insert), but I observe that there is a lot of allocations, as you say, but a corresponding amount of deallocation. Is that expected? It's also logging the IDENT_NEWVAL, and the insertions to the (unclustered) PK index.

Comment: Well, I don't know from the top of my head what the right or wrong things would look like, but if I saw the the log contents I could probably make sense of it. Here is the query I always use for that: http://pastebin.com/YZ215dSY. You can also change it to `TOP 100 ORDER BY NEWID()` to get a representative sample. Be sure to clear the log first.

Comment: @usr, currently tearing my hair out :( Having difficulty finding a sufficiently simplified example which gives repeatable results...

Comment: If you script out the database as well that should give repeatable results. When I ran your scripts I increased the data amount by 100x again to make sure to trigger "bulk behavior" and to cross any thresholds that might be there.